user authentication using spotify web api and pkce
for the past few months ive been trying to use the spotify web api on my android jetpack compose application to authenticate the user and get their currently playing track info as well as personal info but w no success. basically i want a viewmodel that will use the spotify web api to authenticate the user using pkce and will store the access token and also handle refresh tokens while implementing the state system. id really appreciate it if anyone could guide me through the process, thanks in advance!

why does my post fail to attract responses every time?
